# Symfony: A Button to query the database and popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, symfony

I need to create a button that will automatically search in my database all user with a "secouriste" Attribute set and print their firstname, lastname and phone number in a popup.

Here is what I found from my research:

In my HTML, I have to set a button which will enable a popup modal with id of the user I want to get and under this button, there is the code of my popup modal with a listener.
In my JS, I get the data (which is an object).
In Ajax, I need to pass the ID to my controller.
In PHP, I get the ID with a symfony request and FindOneBy.

But there are different problems with this technique: I dont need to get only one person but a list of person with the good attribute so maybe I should use "FindBy" instead of "FindOneBy", but someone said to me that I should use a custom FindAll(). I'm completely lost right now. Here is what I could gather from posts, I know that's far from right, but this is what I have.

```js
//=============================================
//    Recherche PopUp Secouriste
//=============================================
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#secouristeModal', function (e) {
        var id = $('#secouristeModal').data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'UserBundle/utilisateur',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: id
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
         // Si status est égal à true
            if(data.status) {
                console.log(data);

                $('#userTitle').replaceWith(data.user.firstName);
            }
        }).fail(function (data) {
            // Code if error
        });

    })
```

```css
PHP


$user = $this->findBy($request->request->get('secouristeAttribute' -> $secouristeAttribute));

        if($user) {
        return new JSONResponse(array(
        'user' => $user
        ));
        } else {
            // Faire code de retour avec une erreur (status = false)
}

}
```

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#secouristeModal">
                    Liste des secouristes
                </button>

                <!-- Modal des secouristes-->
                <div class="modal fade" id="secouristeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Liste des Secouristes</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<!-- prints a list but doesnt load it from db on request only -->
                            {% for user in workFlow.listeSecouriste|default('')%}
                                {% if user.tel is not null %}
                                    <br />{{ user.username }} - {{ user.nom }} {{ user.prenom }} - {{ user.tel }}
                                {% else %}
                                    <br />{{ user.username }} - {{ user.nom }} {{ user.prenom }}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Exx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can filter your query with a findAll so findBy is good.

But you need to pass an array, something like that:

```
$users = $this->findBy(['attribute' => $request->request->get('secouristeAttribute')]);
```

Also, I'm not really sure about that, but before you return your list of Users you could have to implement `JsonSerializable` Interface with the method `jsonSerialize()` (or at least the `toArray()` magic method).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try that whenever I can, If you happen to think about anything else, please tell me. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem, here is how I did it if it can help someone later:

```js
    //For my popup
    
    function myAlert(message,titre='Information',btn='',class_msg='',fonction,args) {
    //=======================================================

    if (btn==''){
        btn='<a name="btnOk" class="btn btn-success">Ok</a>';
    }
    if (class_msg!='') {
        message='<div class="'+class_msg+'">'+message+'</div>';
    }

    myConfirm(message,titre,btn,fonction,args); // Message d'alerte  
}
```

```css
    //listeSecouriste.html.twig
    
    <ul>{% for secouriste in listeSecouriste |sort secouriste.nom %}
        <li>{{ secouriste.fullName }}  {{ secouriste.tel }}</li>
        {%  endfor %}
    </ul>
```

```html
//php: my controller


    public function getSecours($agence=null){
        $listeSecouriste = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('SIGUserBundle:Utilisateur')->ListeSecouriste($agence);
        $retour=array('ok'=>false);
            if ($listeSecouriste!== null){
                $retour['ok']=true;
                $retour['html']=$this->renderView('SIGUserBundle:Utilisateur:listeSecouriste.html.twig',
                    array(
                        'listeSecouriste'=>$listeSecouriste
                    )
                    );
            }
        return new JsonResponse($retour);
    }
```